# Two methods in Rest resource file with same @Path but different mediaType output

Tags: java, web-services, rest, postman

I have 2 methods in my Java Rest resource file with same @Path uri but different @produces. The code below :

```
@GET
@Path("/messages")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public List<Message> getAllMessages() {


    return new ArrayList<Message>(service.getMessageMap().values());
}

@GET
@Path("/messages")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Message> getAllMessagesJSON() {


    return new ArrayList<Message>(service.getMessageMap().values());
}
```

when i test it with POSTMAN rest client i always get JSON output!!
Can some one explain why?? And if i want to get xml as well as json outputs, what to do??
I tried changing the content-type to application/xml..but i always get json!!

Answer (score 2):

`Content-Type` is for the type of data being sent, either by the client as a *request* header or by the server as a *response* header. So you as a client sending the header is useless, as you are not sending any data. For the client, when it want to tell the server what type it wants, it uses the `Accept: <media-type>` header.

When there is no `Accept` header set, it usually defaults to `*/*` leaving it up for grabs which method to pick in your case.